# xmlns in xml post body causes improper deserialization by Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb

I'm trying to write a Spring controller that reads an xml post request. The root element of the xml that is getting posted looks like this:

```
<booksMessage version="2.0" notificationDate="2013-10-17T00:15:00-08:00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="books:notification:v2.0">
```

My java class that represents that element starts out like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="booksMessage", namespace="books:notification:v2.0")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BooksMessage {
```

When I try to make that post request with Jmeter like that, the object gets translated empty, though. If I take out `xmlns="books:notification:v2.0` from the message being posted, and remove `namespace="books:notification:v2.0"` from my java annotations, it works great. I don't have control over the message that is being posted, though, so how do I get this to work properly when the xml post contains xmlns? Is there some other annotation I have to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root element was in the `books:notification:v2.0` namespace, but all its child elements were in the default namespace, so apparently they never showed. I had to specify the namespace at a package level, and add `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` so that all enclosed elements would automatically have the correct namespace.

To do that, I made a file named "package-info.java" in the package with this in it:

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace="books:notification:v2.0",
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
        )
package com.company.models.books;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;

Comment: Do you have any schema's for this? because if you generate classes with jaxB from schema's it does so much of this work for you. including creating a package-info.java.

Comment: I think maybe I could've gotten ahold of a schema. My experience auto-generating the classes is that it creates a lot of stuff that needs to be fixed anyway, though. (Like superfluous classes for declaring a list.)